# Delete an element from array by update method

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm trying to delete one element from an array in one of the mongoose schema I made. But the pull method doesn't seem to work well for me

I manage to add an element and I'm trying to make it basically the same but in reverse. But the pull method doesn't seem to work for me.

this is my schema

```
userName: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    favorite: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'programs'}]
```

and this is how I'm adding an element to the array

```
router.put('/favorite/:id', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);
        user.favorite.push(req.body.favorite);
        user.save((err, user) => {
            if(err) return console.error(err);
            console.log(user);
        });
        res.json(user);
    })
});
```

here I tried to make it in similar way to remove one element but didn't work, in postman it showed just that it cannot put

```
router.put('favorite/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, user) =>{
        if(err) return console.error(err);
        user.favorite.pull(req.body.favorite);
        user.save((err,user) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log(user);
        });
        res.json(user);
    })
});
```

Basically, I just need to be able to remove the element by its id. I feel like the id should be mentioned somewhere, but I'm not sure where or how. Thanks for all the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend using [`async await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) insted of `callbacks`, `mongoose` supports [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You can also use `mongoose queries` to update fields instead of `JavaScript`, this will reduce the amount of queries to the database.

Also when an error occurs don't forget to send a response to the user to inform that something went wrong.

You tried to use `MongoDB $pull` operator in `JavaScript` instead of using it in the query, you cant use `MongoDB operators` in `JavaScript`

You can also [`destructure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) properties from `req.params` to make it more readable

**Note the id have to be the user document id and favorite have to be the favorite document id**

Now you can add to favorites using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
// to use the await keyword we have to set the callback to an async function
router.put('/favorite/:id', async (req, res) => {
  // destruct id from the req.params object and favorite from req.body
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { favorite } = req.body;
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
      { $push: { favorites: favorite } },
      // new: true means return the updated document
      { new: true },
    );
    res.send(updatedUser);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
  }
});
```

And remove from favorites using [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
router.put('/favorite/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { favorite } = req.body;
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
      { $pull: { favorites: favorite } },
      { new: true },
    );
    res.send(updatedUser);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
  }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this. And in postman, it works with adding the element, but removing it is an issue. I'm writing the correct url and then in body I would write "favorite": "and here the id of the favorite". But it still saying that it cannot put, but doesn't show the 500 code. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @AlbínaMrázová Looks like i forgot a `/` in the delete route, add it and try again.

Comment: That shows up status ok. I noticed just now that it actually doesn't delete anything from the db. The id, that I'm sending in Postman, that I want to delete it is still there after refreshing

Comment: @AlbínaMrázová In the delete route the id is the user id and favorite is the favorite id ?

Comment: exactly like that, yes

Comment: @AlbínaMrázová my bad the favorite is in the `body` and not in `params` updated the answer

Comment: In console it shows that I have the right id's both from the user and from favorite, but it actually doesn't remove the id, I tried several things but at this point, I still cannot figure it out